# TabPage title alignment being wrong after drag'n'dropping

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have the class that extends `System.Windows.Forms.TabControl` and had implemented drag'n'drop mechanism for its `TabPage`s as following:

```
#region Overriden base methods

protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (PointedTabPage == null) return;

    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

    var dragTab = e.Data.GetData(typeof (ManagedTabPage)) as ManagedTabPage;

    if (dragTab == null) return;

    int dropIndex = TabPages.IndexOf(PointedTabPage);
    int dragIndex = TabPages.IndexOf(dragTab);

    if (dragIndex == dropIndex) return;

    var modifiedTabPages = new List<ManagedTabPage>(from ManagedTabPage tabPage in TabPages
                                                    where TabPages.IndexOf(tabPage) != dragIndex
                                                    select TabPages[TabPages.IndexOf(tabPage)] as ManagedTabPage);

    modifiedTabPages.Insert(dropIndex, dragTab);

    for (byte i = 0; i < TabPages.Count; ++i)
    {
        var managedTabPage = TabPages[i] as ManagedTabPage;

        if (managedTabPage != null && managedTabPage.Uid == modifiedTabPages[i].Uid)
            continue;

        TabPages[i] = modifiedTabPages[i];
    }

    SelectedTab = dragTab;
}

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        switch (e.Button)
        {
            case MouseButtons.Left:
                DoDragDrop(PointedTabPage, DragDropEffects.Move);

                break;
            case MouseButtons.Middle:
                CloseTab(PointedTabPage);

                break;
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        TabPages.Insert(0, String.Empty);
        TabPages.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}

#endregion
```

Nota bene that in the `finally` clause of `OnMouseDown` method there are 2 lines for workarounding the
**problem**: for some reason w/o these lines after drag'n'dropping any of `TabPage`s alignment of their titles is being wrong:
[image: draganddrop]

What should I do to correct this behavior without this smelly workaround? Maybe sending some Windows messages could do the trick?
Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

**Edit 1.** Code of `ManagedTabPage` is 100% unimportant (it's just extends `TabPage` with some specific properties).

`PointedTabPage` is unimportant too, but this is it:

```
return (from ManagedTabPage tabPage in TabPages
        let tabPageIndex = TabPages.IndexOf(tabPage)
        where GetTabRect(tabPageIndex).Contains(PointToClient(Cursor.Position))
        select TabPages[tabPageIndex]).Single() as ManagedTabPage;
```

I'm trying to achieve fully-centered alignment of labels. You see, labels on the screenshot didn't *centered horizontally*?

Comment: code example is incomplete now: what is `PointedTabPage`?; `ManagedTabPage` code is probably important. which alignment are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ASh I've made edit, check it out plz

Comment: `PointedTabPage is unimportant too` really strange for you to say so, because `PointedTabPage ` is actively used; CAN"T REPRODUCE ISSUE with given code and TabPage in placeof ManagedTabPage

Comment: @ASh Code is unimportant, because it doesn't have an influence on alignment.

Comment: @ASh Set these properties of your `TabControl`: `AllowDrop = true; SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed; ItemSize = new Size(224, 20);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you hasn't shared `ManagedTabPage` code, i used default `TabPage` control

changes are made in method `OnDragOver`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Demo
{
    public class MyTabControl : TabControl
    {
        public MyTabControl()
        {
            SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed; 
            ItemSize = new Size(224, 20);
        }
```

```
        #region Overriden base methods

        protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DesignMode)
                return;
            if (PointedTabPage == null) return;

            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

            var dragTab = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TabPage)) as TabPage;

            if (dragTab == null) return;

            int dropIndex = TabPages.IndexOf(PointedTabPage);
            int dragIndex = TabPages.IndexOf(dragTab);

            if (dragIndex == dropIndex) return;

            // change position of tab
            TabPages.Remove(dragTab);
            TabPages.Insert(dropIndex, dragTab);

            SelectedTab = dragTab;

            base.OnDragOver(e);
        }
```

```
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DesignMode)
                return;

            switch (e.Button)
            {
                case MouseButtons.Left:
                    DoDragDrop(PointedTabPage, DragDropEffects.Move);                    

                    break;
                case MouseButtons.Middle:
                    TabPages.Remove(PointedTabPage);
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

```
        TabPage PointedTabPage
        {
            get
            {
                return TabPages.OfType<TabPage>()
                    .Where((p, tabPageIndex) => GetTabRect(tabPageIndex).Contains(PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, probably this is what I was looking for. Just some flickering occurs when I do drag'n'dropping. Thanks for your suggestions, bounty is yours.

Answer (score 1):

I can't do much with the posted code.  Let's take a completely different tack and create a tabcontrol that supports dragging a tabpage with the mouse.  Add a new class to your project and paste this code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class TabControlEx : TabControl {
    private Point downPos;
    private Form draggingHost;
    private Rectangle draggingBounds;
    private Point draggingPos;

    public TabControlEx() {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);
    }
}
```

The usage of the variable becomes clear later.  First thing we need is to get mouse events from the TabControl so we can see the user trying to drag a tab.  That requires turning on the UserMouse control style, it is off by default for controls (like TabControl) that are built-in Windows controls and use their own mouse handling.

Use Build > Build and drag the new control from the top of the toolbox onto a form.  Everything still looks and acts like a regular TabControl, but do note that clicking tabs no longer changes the active tab.  A side-effect of turning the UserMouse style on.  Let's fix that first, paste:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    for (int ix = 0; ix < this.TabCount; ++ix) {
        if (this.GetTabRect(ix).Contains(e.Location)) {
            this.SelectedIndex = ix;
            break;
        }
    }
    downPos = e.Location;
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

We are storing the click location, that's needed later to detect the user dragging the tab.  That requires the MouseMove event, we need to start dragging when the user moved the mouse far enough away from the original click position:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && this.TabCount > 1) {
        var delta = SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize;
        if (Math.Abs(e.X - downPos.X) >= delta.Width ||
            Math.Abs(e.Y - downPos.Y) >= delta.Height) {
            startDragging();
        }
    }
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
}
```

The startDragging method needs to create a toplevel window that can be moved around with the mouse, containing a facsimile of the tab we're dragging around.  We'll display it as an owned window, so it is always on top, that has the exact same size as the tab control:

```
private void startDragging() {
    draggingBounds = this.RectangleToScreen(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, this.Size));
    draggingHost = createDraggingHost(draggingBounds);
    draggingPos = Cursor.Position;
    draggingHost.Show(this.FindForm());
}
```

The createDraggingHost needs to do the heavy lifting and create a window that looks just like the tab.  A borderless form we'll move around with the mouse.  We'll use the TransparencyKey property to make it look similar to the dragged TabPage with a tab sticking out at the top.  And make it look the same by simply letting it display a screenshot of the tabpage:

```
private Form createDraggingHost(Rectangle bounds) {
    var host = new Form() { FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None, ControlBox = false, AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None, Bounds = this.draggingBounds, StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual };
    host.BackColor = host.TransparencyKey = Color.Fuchsia;
    var tabRect = this.GetTabRect(this.SelectedIndex);
    var tabImage = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(tabImage)) {
        gr.CopyFromScreen(bounds.Location, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Fuchsia, new Rectangle(0, 0, tabRect.Left, tabRect.Height));
        gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Fuchsia, new Rectangle(tabRect.Right, 0, bounds.Width - tabRect.Right, tabRect.Height));
    }
    host.Capture = true;
    host.MouseCaptureChanged += host_MouseCaptureChanged;
    host.MouseUp += host_MouseCaptureChanged;
    host.MouseMove += host_MouseMove;
    host.Paint += (s, pe) => pe.Graphics.DrawImage(tabImage, 0, 0);
    host.Disposed += delegate { tabImage.Dispose(); };
    return host;
}
```

Note the use of the Capture property, that's how we detect that the user released the mouse button or interrupted the operation by any other means.  We'll use the MouseMove event to move the window around:

```
private void host_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    draggingHost.Location = new Point(draggingBounds.Left + Cursor.Position.X - draggingPos.X, 
                                      draggingBounds.Top + Cursor.Position.Y - draggingPos.Y);

}
```

And finally we need to handle the completion of the drag.  We'll swap tabs, inserting the dragged tab at the mouse position and destroy the window:

```
private void host_MouseCaptureChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (draggingHost.Capture) return;
    var pos = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    for (int ix = 0; ix < this.TabCount; ++ix) {
        if (this.GetTabRect(ix).Contains(pos)) {
            if (ix != this.SelectedIndex) {
                var page = this.SelectedTab;
                this.TabPages.RemoveAt(this.SelectedIndex);
                this.TabPages.Insert(ix, page);
                this.SelectedIndex = ix;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    draggingHost.Dispose();
    draggingHost = null;
}
```

Looks pretty good.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but your suggestion causes UI design modifications. My question was about concrete issue, but not about making draggable controls in general. But upvote anyway.

Comment: It does not, your existing TabControl does not require any UI changes.  Just rename it from TabControl to TabControlEx and delete the code you cannot get going.

Comment: I did that and found that if I drop the tab out of their 'axis', it will not been replaced. Also, draggable tab doesn't detach from its host (`TabControl`). Your solution is pretty beautiful and similar to cool AvalonDock, but my issue was about another. I would prefer to use it in another projects after some calibration and would share with you.

Comment: Also, drag'n'drop works well if I do horizontal mouse movements only.